# Consulta em .NET Core

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core

Estou aprendendo a lógica de MVC aplicado em .NET Core
porém estou com algumas dúvidas em fazer o processo **CRUD**, mais especificamente a *Consulta*.

- Como posso fazer o clique do botão se comunicar com um *Controller* e o mesmo, solicitar a informação para a *Model*, a mesma retornar o resultado para o *Controller* e os resultado serem apresentados na tela?

Segue código.

View.

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.CepViewModel
<h2>Manutenção de Cep</h2>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
<form asp-controller="Cep" asp-action="Cadastro" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">CEP</label>
        <input asp-for="CepCodigo" style="margin-left: 90px" width="50px" />
        <label style="margin-left: 90px" class="control-label">LOGRADOURO</label>
        <input asp-for="CepLogr" style="margin-left: 90px" width="50px" />
        <br />
        <label class="control-label">ENDEREÇO</label>
        <input asp-for="CepEnd" style="margin-left: 40px" width="50px" />
        <label style="margin-left: 90px" class="control-label">COMPLEMENTO</label>
        <input asp-for="CepCompl" style="margin-left: 82px" width="50px" />
        <br />
        <label class="control-label">BAIRRO</label>
        <input asp-for="CepBairro" style="margin-left: 64px" width="50px" />
        <label style="margin-left: 90px" class="control-label">CIDADE</label>
        <input asp-for="CepCidade" style="margin-left: 138px" width="50px" />
        <br />
        <label>UF</label>
        <input asp-for="CepUF" style="margin-left: 100px; width: 50px;" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Consulta" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller.

```
   public class CepController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Cadastro()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Consulta()
        {
            return View();

        }
    }
}
```

Model.

```
    public class CepViewModel
    {
        public string CepCodigo { get; set; }
        public string CepLogr { get; set; }
        public string CepEnd { get; set; }
        public string CepCompl { get; set; }
        public string CepBairro { get; set; }
        public string CepCidade { get; set; }
        public string CepUF { get; set; }
        public int CepSetor { get; set; }
        public string CepRegiao { get; set; }
        public string CepRota { get; set; }


        public CepViewModel TakeCepById(int Id)
        {
            CepViewModel cep = null;

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection("DBConect"))
            {

                cep = connection.Query<CepViewModel>("Select * From CEP WHERE CepCodigo = @CepCodigo",
                        new { CepCodigo = Id }).SingleOrDefault();
                return cep;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Acho que você já resolveu essa, não?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo sim amigo, obrigado!
Mas se quiser compartilhar como aplica sua lógica para esse exemplo, também será bem-vinda

Comment: O Ideal seria você colocar a sua solução e marcar como respondida, para que a questão não fique aberta sem resposta ou removê-la, mas a primeira opção é que trás mais benefício para os outros usuários..

Answer (score 0):

No form você direciona para o controller com a action da sua View:

```
<form asp-controller="Cep" asp-action="Consulta">
```

No controller você indica que esta enviando por POST

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Consulta(int Id)
        {

            return View();
        }
```